# How can I apply a radial gradient for 3d but ONLY for particular charts?

Tags: highcharts

On [this Highcharts Scatter 3d example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/) it applies radial gradient so that the markers are nicer when using 3d. In my case, I also want to use `colorByPoint: true`, but I don't want to apply the radial gradient to ALL charts (as that example does). In my case, I have reports that may show several different charts (some will be using `colorByPoint1 too) and I don't want radial gradient in all of them. Yet, I want the default Highcharts colors.

How can I adapt above example so that the radial gradient is applied ONLY to one instance of a chart?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: what is concrete chart. By the way If you don't want   radial gradient  you can remove it from script i.e `Highcharts.getOptions().colors`

Comment: I just updated my question. By concrete chart I wanted to mean one particular instance (a concrete container ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the demo is set up, the code block at the top is setting the colors for Highcharts, which will be applied to all charts that do not explicitly specify a color set:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {...}
```

What you can do instead is set a variable to hold the radial colors:

```
    // Give the points a 3D feel by adding a radial gradient
    var radColors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
        return {
            radialGradient: {
                cx: 0.4,
                cy: 0.3,
                r: 0.5
            },
            stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.2).get('rgb')]
            ]
        };
    });
```

And then specify that variable as the `colors` property for the chart(s) that you want to use it for:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  colors: radColors,
  chart: { ... }
  ...
});
```

Updated Fiddle with multiple charts:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ubeh1wbo/

You could create any number of color set variables and provide them to different chart types as needed.